# The return type of a forms object

Tags: c#, winforms

Below is an example of what is automatically generated by Visual Studio when you create a new form item.

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) // background color
    {
    }
```

Below is my `getter`.

```
    public type comboBox2Object { // text color
        get {
            return this.comboBox2;
        }
    }
```

I would like to be able to use something like `settings.comboBox2Object.Text` in my main method, and thus my question is - what should I set the return type of my getter method as?

**Note:**

Previously, this is how I did it:

```
    public type comboBox2Color { // text color
        get {
            return this.comboBox2.Text;
        }
    }
```

However, the properties start to pile up quick, thus I'm interested in returning just the comboBox object, and use the respective methods like `.SelectedIndex`, `Enabled`, etc, in my main method.

Comment: Visual Studio does not auto create events when you add control items to a form. That happens when you doubleclick an event in the properties window (event tab) for that form item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your return `type` is the type you specify in your property:

```
public ComboBox MyComboBox {
    get { return this.comboBox2; }
}
```

In this and your example, your return type to return a ComboBox should match the return type of your property and it is a `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`. This property will return a reference to your `this.comboBox2`.

For more information you can refer to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) documentation

Comment: I know this, but my question was in regards to returning the object, instead of simply just `this.comboBox2.Text`. Meaning, I want to return `this.comboBox2`